# docker how to commit a docker with a new command with quotation signs

Tags: docker, nginx, command-line-arguments

In the process of am making a docker, I have to change its command from /bin/sh to `nginx -g "daemon off;"` (exactly that).

I wrote:

```
docker commit --change="EXPOSE 80" --change='CMD ["nginx", "-g", "\"daemon off;\""]' ${arr[0]} mine/nginx_final
```

Where `${arr[0]}` expands to the correct docker container.

However when I try to run this docker it fails with the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
```

Docker inspect also doesn't show anything bad:

```
        "Cmd": [
            "nginx",
            "-g",
            "\"daemon off;\""
        ],
```

expected, and i expect the `"\"daemon off;\""` to expand to "daemon off;"

Yet I'm pretty sure there is a `;` sign after `deamon off`. Where did this sign go? And how can I debug this? (And fix it)

Comment: Why not use a Dockerfile?

Comment: You don't need to quote arguments in a CMD array as they are passed directly to exec the process, not through a shell. `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` will do. Not sure that would fix the problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nginx can't process a global directive that includes quotes: `"daemon off;"`

```
docker commit \
  --change='EXPOSE 80' \
  --change='CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]' \
  ${arr[0]} \
  mine/nginx_final
```

#### Exec Form

[`CMD ["foo"]`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) is called the *exec* form. A process will be run via [`exec`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) rather than via a shell. Each element in the array becomes an argument to exec. The extra `"` quotes are being passed through to nginx:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "\"daemon off;\""]
exec('nginx', '-g', '"daemon off;"')
```

Using the exec form already passes the space on unaltered so all you need is:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
exec('nginx' '-g' 'daemon off;')
```

#### Shell Form

[`CMD foo`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) is called the *shell* form. The global directive argument with spaces would need quoting here:

```
CMD nginx -g "daemon off;"
exec('sh', '-c', 'nginx -g "daemon off;"')
exec('nginx', '-g', 'daemon off;')
```

Other wise the shell interpreting the command will split arguments on spaces and try and exec `nginx` with 3 arguments:

```
CMD nginx -g daemon off;
exec('sh', '-c', 'nginx -g daemon off;')
exec('nginx', '-g', 'daemon', 'off;')
```