# Local nginx service can't start and error 256 is given

Tags: nginx, homebrew, laravel-valet

I'm trying to see locally in my browsers (Chrome, Firefox and safary tested) some proyects parked with Valet developed in Laravel.

Currently, no response is received when I visit some of the local sites url.

## Current status

the output of the command `sudo brew services list`:
[image]

I found this lint on nginx log erros in file */opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/error.log*:
`2023/04/24 02:30:55 [emerg] 17880#0: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line`

The installation of Valet and nginx are untouched.

I've run the command `sudo nginx -t` and the output is:

```
nginx: the configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

## Services installation folder

```
which nginx
/opt/homebrew/bin/nginx
```

```
which dnsmasq
/opt/homebrew/sbin/dnsmasq
```

```
which php
/opt/homebrew/bin/php
```

(test if apache2 is installed and generating conflicts)

```
which apache2
apache2 not found
```

## Infrastructure

Macos Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261), M1 ARM64

I tried the following things:

1. Restart Valet
2. Restart notebook
3. Reinstall Valet
4. Ask chatGPT what means the log line in error.log for nginx
5. Search in stackoverflow similar experiences
6. Using links instead of park sites on Valet
7. Replace Valet with `artisan serve` (it works, but I don't want that)

**Edit:**
I'm not using docker for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker how to commit a docker with a new command with quotation signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419021/docker-how-to-commit-a-docker-with-a-new-command-with-quotation-signs) alternatively, any of the other search results for [unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line](https://www.google.com/search?q=unexpected+end+of+parameter%2C+expecting+%22%3B%22+in+command+line)